# Style v-html Vue 3

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, css-modules

For some reason this is working in Vue 3 which says is deprecated in every other SO answer:

```
.description >>> p {
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

But I've tried all the permutations of ::v-deep and can't seem to make it work:

```
::v-deep .description {
  p {
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}

.description {
  ::v-deep p {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}
```

How would I do this with "vanilla" Vue 3?

```
<div class="description text-sm">
  <div v-html="item.description"></div>
</div>
```

What I would like to work:

```
<style scoped>
.description p {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why would a simple `.description p` not work?

Comment: because I want a scoped style

Comment: oh, I have tried that, simply `.description p` in the scoped css block didnt work. I have no idea why......

Comment: Okay but does it work without the scoped syntax? The browser certainly cannot refuse to color the element.. The `p` tags definitely exist in the output? Can you add an example `item.description` just to be complete? Or make this a snippet entirely?

Comment: Ah, the point is I don't want a global style, I want a scope style to this component. Yes that would work, but it also dirties my sheet up with global styles which I'm not wanting to do

Comment: This was getting long, posted an answer with some more clarification. Please create a working snippet from your code to analyze further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is obvious in retrospect after looking at the example on [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

The problem was that I thought nesting was required, or that it had to preceed the target selector.

In actuality, its identical to this:

```
.description >>> p {
    margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

...except that `>>>` is replaced with `::v-deep`, **which requires removing the space because it's a pseudo-class, just like regular css**

This will work:

```
.description::v-deep p {
    margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a component's style scoped with the `scoped` attribute.
All selectors will be prefixed automatically so that the style only applies to this component. It is not clear from your example code if you have that, so let's give the example:

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.description {
  p {
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}
</style>
```

Is `::v-deep` still needed this way? v-deep doesn't make it more scoped.
Can you check in the resulting CSS what that compiles to?

Can you create a full snippet with your code to test here?

Comment: I added a comment with my scoped css. Is there a way to achieve it without scss? I put what I tried above

Comment: I see. Have you tried with `lang="scss"` just for testing? This may change the processing of your styles depending on your configuration. You should create an executable code snippet to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:deep {}`

In your case you should do:

```
<template>
   <div class="description" v-html="item.description"></div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.description {
   :deep {
      p {
         margin-bottom: 1rem;
      }
   }
}
</style>
```